# taking "screenshot" of a variable height webview in iOS

Tags: ios, uiwebview, webview, screenshot

Can anyone point me to some sample code for capturing an image of a full webview that is embedded within an iphone app? The webview is variable height depending on the content, so a simple screenshot won't do the trick for users, but I'd like to give them a button in the nav bar that captures a full-height image and saves it to their photo library.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you find the width and height of the Webview?

Comment: webview haev a page length property as well as a page count property, maybe you can use these values to for a split second resize your uiwebview then take a screen shot of the resized webviews layer, then reset the original width and height.

Answer (score 0):

As `UIWebView` presents content on the `UIScrollView`, you could start making screenshot from top to bottom, by changing `contentOffset` parameter of `UIScrollView`, and joining the screenshots. And, remember to check the `contentSize`. Good Luck!

Answer (score -2):

Use this code:

```
    - (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender 
{
    webViewHeight = [[self.myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollHeight;"] integerValue];

CGRect screenRect = self.myWebView.frame;

double currentWebViewHeight = webViewHeight;
while (currentWebViewHeight > 0)
{
    imageName ++;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenRect.size);

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [[UIColor blackColor] set];
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, screenRect);

    [self.myWebView.layer renderInContext:ctx];

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *pngPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",imageName]];

    if(currentWebViewHeight < 960)
    {
        CGRect lastImageRect = CGRectMake(0, 960 - currentWebViewHeight, self.myWebView.frame.size.width, currentWebViewHeight);
        CGImageRef lastImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([newImage CGImage], lastImageRect);                
        newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:lastImageRef]; 
        CGImageRelease(lastImageRef);
    }

    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImage) writeToFile:pngPath atomically:YES];

    [self.myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.scrollBy(0,960);"];
    currentWebViewHeight -= 960;
 }
 }
```